# Destroy old Apple IDs from my iPhone

Tags: apple-id

I created three Apple IDs on my iPhone. I have signed out of all three IDs one by one. However now I am not able to create a new Apple ID on my iPhone.

Comment: Why did you need to create three, and why do you need to create more? You only need one Apple ID.

Comment: For some strange reason there is a limit to how many can be _created_ per device.  You might be able to create via appleid.apple.com but there seems to be some sort of limit there as well, that is less easy to define.  Why are you creating so many?

Comment: @Tyson Given that any one person only needs one (maybe if you twisted my arm I could get on board with needing two), why would it be _strange_ that there's a limit on how many can be created?

Comment: Can you add some details about why you want to create a new Apple ID in the first place? If it is "just" a case of forgotten password there are other ways to resolve that.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot 'destroy' Apple IDs, they last forever.
2. You only need **one** ID. You can [change the associated email address](https://support.apple.com/HT202667) if needed.
3. The ID used to set up the phone or to download any software is the only one that can ever update or restore it.
4. Giving someone else your ID & password details is a security nightmare & foolish in the extreme - open to abuse at any time in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest creating Apple ID via web page instead of iPhone. The sign in page:
https://discussions.apple.com/login.jspa (click 'create one now' on the right).

P.S. If you should sign out all the apps associated with Apple ID, including iMessages, iTunes Store, App Store, etc...